# Rails - how to display a name related to an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a (hopefully) simple question that might have been answered before.. i just couldnt find it... well, here we go, should be easy enough.

I have this schema

```
create_table "items", :force => true do |t|
t.text     "description"
t.string   "priority"
t.date     "date"
t.time     "time"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.boolean  "done"
t.integer  "user_id"
end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

And I have this in my form for adding a new item:

```
<%= collection_select(:item, :user_id, User.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Now, it works, data is saved correctly (I already set up the proper correlations). What i want though, is to display in the items index, the name of the person the item is assigned to, instead of just an ID number.

In items/index I have:

```
<td><%= item.user_id. %></td>
```

but i rather want something like

```
item.user.name
```

only, it won't work - I guess I need some action in my controller.
Can you help me please? :)

EDIT here is some more details:
My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your Items class:

```
class Items < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Then `item.user.name` should work.

Comment: I already have 
belongs_to :user
in item.rb model, and 
has_many :items
in user.rb model
still they won't work :(

Comment: I have

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end

Comment: It should be singular named class 'Item'


What error do you get ?

Comment: Showing /home/alex/Documents/Web/myapp/app/views/items/index.html.erb where line #21 raised:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

line 21 is:  <td><%= item.user.name %></td>

Comment: Well, this means that the user is nil and so it obviously has no name. If you print that item with `puts item.attributes` you'll see that its user_id is null.

Comment: yea! indeed one of the items in my list had no attached user so i was getting the error above... how stupid! Now it's fixed! Which answer should I mark as correct? Thanks ashitaka!

Comment: I actually have no idea of how to mark a question answered without marking a certain answer correctly. In this case I guess nobody was right (and I even steered you away from the correct path). You yourself managed to understand what was wrong and you came up with the right solution so I guess you're the one who deserves the props. Good luck with your project!

Comment: @Alex:  The lesson is always give a stack trace instead of just saying "it won't work"